# edmx not taking defaults from DB

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, edmx

Here is my scenario. I have a SQL Server database that I am using as the backend. And my application is in ASP.net. I have defined defaults for 2 of the columns in the DB table, table name is `Car`.

1. One of the columns in the `Car` table is called `Qty` and it's type is `Int`. I have set a default for this column in the database as 0 (zero)
2. Another column in the `Car` table is called `Model` and it's type is `nvarchar(50)`. I have set a default for this column in the database as `*`

I want these defaults to show up in the edmx as well. My intention is that when I declare a new instance of class `Car` in code, I want the default value of `Qty` to show up as 0 (instead of null) and I want the default value of `Model` to show up as `*` (instead of null).

So after doing quite a bit of reading I realized that I need to set `StoageGeneratedPattern = Computer` for both `Qty` and `Model` in the edmx file.

It works perfectly for `Qty`. When I define a new instance of class `Car` and look at the properties, I see that `Qty` is 0. **BUT** for `Model`, the default is still `null` (instead of `*`).

Here is what I have done. I have set `nullable = false` and `StorageGeneratedPattern = Computed`, in the CSDL content and in the SSDL content of the edmx file. I still can't seem to get `*` as the default value for `Model`. What am I missing here?